# React Bootstrap 3 - FormControl.Feedback messaging

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use React Bootstrap V3's FormControl.Feedback to display different error messages similar to how its done in Bootstrap v4, is this possible? The only supporting documentation I've found is that its used to simply display an icon in the forms input area?

My current thought is I can use the validationState, which my handleAction method will set to one of either null, success, or error. Based on that state, is there a tag or something I can set in the FormControl block to display various messages based on the state?

```
<FormGroup controlId="formBasicText" validationState={this.state.nameState} bsClass='form-group required'>
    <ControlLabel>Name</ControlLabel>
    <FormControl maxLength='4000' name="name" type="text" value={this.state.name} placeholder="Name" onChange={this.handleChange} onBlur={this.handleChange}/>
    <FormControl.Feedback/>
    <HelpBlock className="text-danger">{this.state.nameError}</HelpBlock>
</FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done some research and I found that the form validation was not in bootstrap v3. As `React-bootstrap v(0.x)` was based on `bootstrap v3` and they have manually implemented icon-based form validation.
To implement form validation, you can define your own wrapper component.

let's say the component name is `ValidationMessage`

> Sending custom message that you want to show based on state(Basic one)

```js
const ValidationMessage = ({type, message, ...props}) => ( 
   // will not render when type is null or undefined
   type ? <div className=`validation-msg-${type}`>{message}</div> : null 
)
```

and you can use it like below

```js
<ValidationMessage type='success' message= "custom message for success'/>
```

> Else you can make it little more usable like below

```js
const ValidationMessage = ({type, message, ...props}) => {
 const getMessage = type => {
   // Define fixed messages that you can use everywhere
   switch(type) {
     case 'error'
      return 'error text';
     case 'warning'
      return 'warning text';
     case 'success'
      return 'success text';
     default:
      return;
   }
 }

 // will not render when type is null or undefined
 return ( type ? <div className=`validation-msg-${type}`>{message || getMessage(type)}</div> : null)
}
```

and you can use it like below

```js
<ValidationMessage type='success' />
```